# CTRL+= shortcut binding in MacOS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

I've a binding for `CTRL =` shortcut in emacs. It works when I use emacs as an app. But in the terminal, `CTRL =` causes "invalid key sound" and also doesn't work in terminal emacs. What's blocking it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382796/why-is-ctrl-shortcut-blocked

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<CTRL-=>` *is* an invalid key combination in a terminal interface.

(Hint:  There's no such corresponding ASCII character.)